# setting font of title

Tags: html

When giving title to a web page is it possible to change the font of the title?
for example:
`<html>
     <title> Question </title>
 </html>`

*Now if i want to set the font of title 'question' to be what i want,then how can i do it?*

Answer (score 4):

No. See the standard.

> Titles may contain character entities (for accented characters, special characters, etc.), but may not contain other markup (including comments).

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.2

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible with all of the most commonly used browsers.

Comment: @ marcgg what do you mean by `...most commonly used browsers.`?

Comment: It means you could write your own browser, perhaps forking from one of the open source browsers, to do this.... but none of the big name browsers (or even smaller name ones) like IE, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, Lunascape, Lynx, etc will allow you to set the style for the title

Comment: Even if you wrote your own custom browser, you'd run into issues.  The window manager generally is what sets the style of the window title, and it prefers to use the same settings for everybody.  You'd probably have to hijack the non-client-area paint messages in order to make it work.  Probably why no browser goes through the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The only special thing you can do with title text is changing the text direction between left-to-right and right-to-left

Answer (score 0):

I presume you'd like to add style to the title as it appears in the **Search Engine results**?  Alas, web crawlers don't support this functionality (though one of either category could actually be built to support title styles).  However, you can achieve a distinct look by using non-ASCII characters (IPA or Greek or Russian) or punctuation.

If you're looking for a distinct look in your title in the **browser window** (e.g. in the tab) a custom favicon may be of use (it's the tiny image that appears in the browser next to your title).  This thread discusses how to do that: [How do I put image in url in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164813/how-do-i-put-image-in-url-in-html)